# Ambiguous error when using INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to select deptno, dname from the depts table and join it with the emp table to select empno and ename.  Then I want group them by department name by sort by deptno ascending.
  When joining these two tables I keep getting 'deptno' is ambiguous. But that is the commonality to join the tables. Any helpful advice where my error may be with

```
SELECT deptno, dname, empno, ename
FROM dept INNER JOIN emp
ON dept.deptno = emp.deptno
GROUP BY dname
ORDER BY deptno ASC;
```

Thank you for any helpful advice.

Answer (score 5):

Ambiguity arises from the `deptno` field, which is present in both the `dept` and `emp` tables. To avoid it use qualified names or aliases.

```
SELECT D.deptno, dname, empno, ename
FROM dept D
    INNER JOIN emp E
        ON D.deptno = E.deptno
GROUP BY dname
ORDER BY D.deptno ASC;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT dept.deptno, dname, empno, ename FROM dept INNER JOIN emp ON dept.deptno = emp.deptno   
GROUP BY dname ORDER BY dept.deptno ASC;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have `deptno` in both tables but you are not specifying which table to return in both the `SELECT` and `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT dept.deptno, dname, empno, ename
FROM dept 
INNER JOIN emp
  ON dept.deptno = emp.deptno
GROUP BY dname
ORDER BY dept.deptno ASC;
```

Or

```
SELECT emp.deptno, dname, empno, ename
FROM dept 
INNER JOIN emp
  ON dept.deptno = emp.deptno
GROUP BY dname
ORDER BY emp.deptno ASC;
```

If you do not specify the table for `deptno`, then you will get this error message.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 SELECT dept.deptno, dname, empno, ename
 FROM dept INNER JOIN emp
 ON dept.deptno = emp.deptno
 GROUP BY dname
 ORDER BY dept.deptno ASC;
```